# How to draw a moving repeating pattern on an html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a wall that moves on the screen from right to left that is drawn on an HTML5 canvas.  I'm using a repeating pattern of an image of bricks to make it appear like the entire wall is covered in bricks.

Here's the relevant code that creates and fills the pattern:

```
this.update = function() {
    var context = gCanvas.context;
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this.image, "repeat");
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};
```

The wall moves from right to left, but the pattern does not move with it, making it appear like the pattern is a static image and the wall is scrolling across it.  What I need is for the pattern to follow the wall to make it appear like the entire wall is moving from right to left.

Please see the following jsfiddle to see this in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/ugmo1cd3/4/

Comment: Flappy bird, huh?

Comment: @Bernard, ha, yep you got it.  Actually my version is called "Robotman" and it's published here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/robotman/cjpdlmjbocfbhjgdpmfkcphkacmighmb?hl=en-US&gl=US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the Wall update functions into

```
this.update = function() {
    var context = gCanvas.context;
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this.image, "repeat");
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    context.restore();
};
```

The pattern will now start at the (x,y) and not at the (0,0) of the canvas

Comment: You can also move the `createPattern` into the constructor: `this.PAT = gCanvas.context.createPattern(this.image, "repeat");` and then use the `PAT` in the update function, in order to stop creating in every update

Comment: that is exactly what I needed!  Upvoted and accepted answer, and it still doesn't seem like enough.  Thanks!  FYI - this was the last little bit to get me over the finish to create my game - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/robotman/cjpdlmjbocfbhjgdpmfkcphkacmighmb?hl=en-US&gl=US.  You can feel like you had a part in it now. :)